# std::make_array<size_t> from signed int

Tags: c++, arrays, language-lawyer, c++17

Given a code:

```
constexpr auto a = std::make_array<size_t>(1, 2, 3);
```

Clang (3.7) with a realization copied from GCC's [libstdc++v3 experimental/array](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/experimental/array) gives this warning:

```
error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'value_type' (aka 'unsigned long') in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
return {{ std::forward<Types>(t)... }};
```

Is this legal when a compiler knows at compile-time, that 1, 2 and 3 can be implicitly converted to `size_t`?

It gives no warning when I write:

```
constexpr std::array<size_t, 3> a{1, 2, 3};
```

And `std::make_array` is supposed to be the same as this construction.

It is more theoretical than practical question.

Bonus question: how can `std::make_array` be corrected in GCC's realization to accept code given above?

GCC's realization:

```
template <typename _Dest = void, typename... _Types>
  constexpr auto
  make_array(_Types&&... __t)
    -> array<conditional_t<is_void_v<_Dest>,
                           common_type_t<_Types...>,
                           _Dest>,
             sizeof...(_Types)>
  {
    static_assert(__or_<
                  __not_<is_void<_Dest>>,
                  __and_<__not_<__is_reference_wrapper<decay_t<_Types>>>...>>
                  ::value,
                  "make_array cannot be used without an explicit target type "
                  "if any of the types given is a reference_wrapper");
    return {{forward<_Types>(__t)...}};
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `std::make_array` is not supposed to be the same as that construction.

`std::make_array` takes `Types&&...`, which requires determining the types from the arguments, and in your case produces parameters of type `int`. Inside `make_array`, you no longer have constant values, so the exception that in-range constant integer values can be converted inside `{}` no longer applies.

A different example is `std::array<void*, 1>{0}` vs. `std::make_array<void*>(0)`. The former is valid, since `0` is convertible to any pointer type. The latter is invalid, since an integer parameter which happens to have the value `0` is not implicitly convertible to any pointer type.

Comment: Is it prescripted by the Standard, or it is a consequence of the realization?

Comment: @vladon It's required by [this proposal to add it](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4391.html), but I'm not sure if that's the most up-to-date description.

Comment: If it helps, the current wording is from [N4617](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4617.pdf) §9.2.2 and [P0325](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0325r1.html).

Comment: @ildjarn That shows an example was added specifically pointing out the problem that the OP here is asking about, so thanks for the link :)